# Ошибка, связаная с require("chalk")

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let hash = require('object-hash');


const TARGET_HASH = 20;

let validator = require("./validator");

let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let blockChainModel = mongoose.model("BlockChain");

let chalk = require("chalk");

// import chalk from 'chalk';


class BlockChain{

    constructor(){
        this.chain = [];
        this.curr_transactions = [];

    }

    addNewBlock(prevHash){
        let block = {
            index: this.chain.length + 1,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            transactions: this.curr_transactions,
            prevHash: prevHash,
        };

        if(validator.proofOfWork() == TARGET_HASH){
            block.hash = hash(block);
            let newBlock = new blockChainModel(this.block);
            newBlock.save((err) => {
                if(err) return console.log(chalk.red("Blok not added to db", err.message));
                console.log(chalk.green("block added to db"));
            });

            
        this.chain.push(block);
        this.curr_transactions = [];
        return block;


        }
    }


    addNewTransaction(sender, recipient, amount){
        this.curr_transactions.push({sender, recipient, amount});
    }

    lastBlock(){
        return this.chain.slice(-1)[0];
    }

    isEmpty(){
        return this.chain.length == 0;
    }

}

module.exports = BlockChain;
```

Ошибка: let chalk = require("chalk");
^

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\...\blockchain_bazadanych\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from C:\Users\...\blockchain_bazadanych\blockChain.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\losas\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\blockchain_bazadanych\blockChain.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Попробовал заменить

```
let chalk = require("chalk"); на import chalk from 'chalk'; и добавил "type": "module", в package.json( 

    {
      "dependencies": {
        "type": "module",
        "chalk": "^5.2.0",
        "mongodb": "^5.0.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.9.1",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "object-hash": "^3.0.0"
        
      }
    }, не помогло
```

Comment: chalk давно esm. переведите проект на esm, `”type”: “module”` или понизьте версию пакета до той, что поддерживала commonjs

Comment: `"type": "module"` нужно указывать не в dependencies, а на самом верхнем уровне JSON'a